# Two busses arrive randomly between 7:00-7:30. Whats the probability that the second bus will arrive exactly at the time of the first?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

At a bus stop, two busses arrive randomly between 7:00-7:30. You start waiting at the bus stop from 7:00. What is the probably that you hop on a bus at a certain time, and the other bus shows up at that exact time?
Assume your watch doesn't have a hand displaying seconds passed. Your "Time axis" is the group of lone minutes 1-30)

Questions:

1.) On Sunday, you hopped on the bus that arrived at 7:10. What is the probability that another bus will arrive exactly at 7:10?

2.) Given that the first bus arrives at minute T $\in$ {0,1,...,29}, calculate the probability that the second bus also arrives at minute T. Assume that as the busses arrive late (that is, T increases), the chances that both of them arrive simultaneously increases.

Attempted Answer:

There are 30 (1-30) individual minutes that the busses can arrive at, and thus our probability space is 30.

1.) Correct me if I'm wrong, but if the first bus arrives at 7:10, then the chances the second bus arrives are 1/20. You hop on the first bus that arrives, therefore the only times that bus #2 can arrive are from 7:10 until 7:30. He must arrive at that exact minute, out of 20 possible options of minutes.

With question #2 I'm having quite a difficult time beginning. From what I can understand, we're looking for a general probability function that'll calculate what we did for #1 but for any given time.

Comment: time is continuous. you cannot say minutes are the smallest discrete value. try using geometric probability.

Comment: @K.Jiang sorry should've added that part to my question. It's given that minutes are the smallest values

Comment: that's fine. then you would be correct for #1

Comment: If 7:00 and 7:30 are included its 1/31

Comment: There's this phrase "Assume that as the buses arrive late (that is, T increases), the chances that both of them arrive simultaneously increases."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets call the buses A and B.  I suggest you draw up a matrix of the times that the buses could show up.  You don't need to fill in all of the entries, a big box with the times bus A shows up on the x axis and B shows up on the y axis.

Neither bus shows up before the 10 minute mark, so we can exclude a large chunk of data from the Matrix.  That leaves a 20 x 20 grid when buses might arrive.  Of the 400, 20 of them have A showing up at 7:10.  20 have B showing up at 7:10, and one overlaps.

P(A = B| min(A,B) = 10) = 1/ 39

part 2:

P(A = B| min(A,B) = T) = 1/ [(30-T)+(30-T-1)]

P(A = B| min(A,B) = T) = 1/ (59-2T)